# Test spark failover

Tags: scala, apache-spark, testing

In my project I perform some side effects inside RDD's actions and transformations. I want to test that my business logic works even if Spark engine had to retry computations for some partitions.
So I'm trying to simulate failures during the computation.

```
object Test extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  conf.setMaster("local[4]")
  conf.setAppName(getClass.getName)
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  try {
    val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
    val res = data.map(n => {
      if (TaskContext.get().attemptNumber() == 0 && n==5) {
        sys.error("boom!")
      }
      n * 2
    }).collect()
  }
  finally {
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work: exception is propagated to a driver.
Seems that the Spark tries to failover only its internal errors.
Is there any way to test it?

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that you are likely to make a mistake in you program and the understanding of fault-tolerant computing mechanism with spark.

first of all, please refer the [scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/sys/package.html), **especially this function**:

`def error(message: String): Nothing`

**Throw a new RuntimeException with the supplied message**.

**if you insert this code in your program, without catch exception statement follow it, the invoking of this function would lead a runtime exception and will make the current process terminated**.

And this is not related with spark's fault-tolerant computing mechanism, this is just related with the process and the operating system it runs on! runtime exception without catch will lead the control flow (aka.current process) to be terminated.

**but, what is the fault-tolerant computing mechanism of spark?**

It is about at internal of spark, it use multi-replication to guarantee computing safely, each task of one specific spark application can be crashed, with many possible reasons, such as network io failure.

but by using a clever trick, the driver node sustain lineage of dependencies of rdds.
then any partition(aka.task) can be re-computed from the original dataset using the lineage of drive node.

**It is about application(spark) level, not the os + process level.**